# How do I solve File Open button not working in JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

I opened JMeter using .bat file. And 'Open' button under file menu does not throw any pop-up windows explorer window.[Not working button shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXOXW.png)
[cmd error after clicking 'open' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3s4T.png)

Comment: Can you please provide more details? 1. OS 2. Jmeter version 3. JDK version 4. Have you done any changes to JMeter setting (e.g Options --Look and Feel)

Answer (score 2):

It's a consequence of the [JMeter Bug 65300](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65300), the options are in:

1. Use another Look and Feel (avoiding `Darklaf` ones)

   [image]
2. Try out the [nightly build of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html), there is a chance that the issue is fixed there
3. Downgrade to [Java 8](http://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/8-MR3), it's the minimum version required to launch [JMeter 5.4](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities) as these restrictions are specific to Java9+
4. If you cannot downgrade Java for any reason and cannot use the nightly builds you can change [line 112 of jmeter.bat script](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/jmeter.bat#L112) to look like

   ```
   set JAVA9_OPTS=--add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED
   ```